# How to setup Sub Domains with internal and external DNS Configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, subdomain, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8

I am setting up a mail server and a few other application servers which will need to be accessed from both inside and outside the organisation via web browser. I would like to create sub domains for all these web servers to make things consistent.
Our public website is example.vic.edu.au and our Windows domain is example.local. The website is hosted at weebly but I do have full control over the DNS configuration.
These are some of the web/application servers I will be setting up and the way I would like to have sub domains setup:
Type, Platform, URL
Email, IIS(MS Exchange 2013), mail.example.vic.edu.au
Intranet, IIS, intranet.example.vic.edu.au
helpdesk, Apache, helpdesk.example.vic.edu.au
Library, Apache/IIS, library.example.vic.edu.au
Moodle, Apache, moodle.example.vic.edu.au

I would also like to use SSL certificates for all these sites.
Can anyone please advise me how this can be achieved and what do I need to do so the users can access all these sites from outside and inside the organisation by using the same URLs. Moreover, when inside it should resolve to the local ip address of the server so the traffic stays local.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its quiet simple. You just setup a single subdomain. And in the internal DNS you add the subdomain entry leading to the local ip. Where as for the outside links the subdomain will be redirected to the public ip address which has been set by default.

For the SSL certificates, if you are using a loadbalancer then to upload the SSl on it. Else you will have to configure manually on each server.

Comment: So do you mean in Windows Server DNS, I create new a domain under Forward Lookup Zones? Will I need multiple public IP addresses to accomplish this. Is there a way to do this with only one public IP address. Can I upload the SSL certificate on the firewall I am using?

Comment: Also, what if I want to use sub-folders instead of sub-domains. Is is possible in this scenario?

Comment: Yes you have to create entries in the DNS server for the proper redirection. To use one public address you will need a load balancer. Loadbalancer has one public address and you can put multiple servers behind it. There are other methods too but loadbalancer one is the easiest. For the second question. No. DNS configuration doesn't work that way.